# UITableViewController not re-firing when using outside modal controller to input data

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` that allows for adding to it's cells through another `TableviewController` where the user can enter their data. I am passing the `NSString` data back to the first `TableViewController` properly as the `NSLog` states. However, the first `TableViewController` is not re-firing. I believe this is caused because I am using a modal transition. Would somebody explain to me how to make a `UITableViewController` re-fire with modal transitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

after adding to the table input array(datasource )
call

```
   [tableView reloadData];
```